# View logs from Fortigate SSLVPN client for windows

Tags: vpn, fortigate

I have some users that have trouble when connecting to my vpn, I want to see what the errors look like on the user side, hence I enabled the debugging in the client at "Log Level -> Debug" (where you go to see the about information)
Where is that information dumped? I can't find any information on internet :(

The client I am using is the sslvpn client (Not the forticlient), the manual page is [here](http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/50/index.html#page/FortiOS%25205.0%2520Help/SSLVPN_Client_41.162.3.html), but there is no help other than the basic configuration.

Comment: http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/50/index.html#page/FortiOS 5.0 Help/SSLVPN_FortiGate_41.161.43.html

Comment: @mbrownnyc just added the link to main post

Comment: Looks like the link I pasted didn't "hotlink" (remember that word?).  Try [this](http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/50/index.html#page/FortiOS%25205.0%2520Help/SSLVPN_FortiGate_41.161.43.html)

Comment: Hi @mbrownnyc the logging I am looking for is the one in the client, not the server.

Comment: Don't want to leave you hanging... here are some links I found with google: [SSL VPN Troubleshooting](http://docs-legacy.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/50/index.html#page/FortiOS%205.0%20Help/SSLVPN_FortiGate_41.161.45.html), [debugging at the Fortigate CLI](http://igetcomputers.com/blog/?p=49), [common ssl vpn problems](http://adminramble.com/common-forticlient-ssl-vpn-errors/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out the solution, the logs are placed in the user appdata folder. So you should just go to:

> %APPDATA%/Fortinet/SslvpnClient/LogFiles/

Unfortunately those logs are not terribly useful (at least in the case I checked), but still might have something interesting.